# Change props of parent view in react native

Tags: react-native

I am using react native and for routing I use react-native-router-flux. My issue is that I want to change the props of a parent view by clicking on a button on my child view.

Route.js:

```
...
<Scene key="test" type="replace">
  <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="Home"/>
  <Scene key="home2" component={HomeTwo} />
</Scene>
```

Home.js:

```
...
constructor(){
super();
this.state = {
    loading: this.loading
};
...

_goToNextScene(){
    Actions.home2();
}
```

HomeTwo.js:

```
_changeProps() {
//here I want to change state loading of parentview Home
}
```

Is this even possible?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried 
`Actions.home2({loading:this.state.loading} )` ?

Comment: Can I change the props then on HomeTwo-View, which is actually my child-view of Home? So if use the backbutton the "this.state.loading" is changed on Home?

Comment: You may use Actions.pop();Actions.refresh(DATA) for back button to update parent view...

Comment: How can I change the functionality of back button? My main problem is, that if I am at child view the parent view is still working in background. If I could stop the parent view like in android with onPause and onResume to start it again when I come back it would be great...

Comment: Sorry, it seems React-related question not, about this component